# Search word with wildcard in a string PHP and RegEx

Tags: php, regex, string, pcre

a form pass a string with wildcard characters (*) to the php page, I need to retrive all the matching words in a text file already on the server.

I think regex is a good way.

here a little piece of code:

```
$w= 'h**e'; // example of word 

$matches=array();


$filename = 'words.txt'; //txt file

$words= file_get_contents ( $filename); //read file
$w=str_replace ("*", '\w',$w); //replace * with \w

preg_match_all('/'.$w.'/', $words, $matches); // get all matching string


var_dump($matches[0]); //print var
```

I replace wildcar char * with \w, this way I can find many occurences, for example i found 'hope' and 'hype', but also 'hopeless'. I need only the words with the correct length.

I'm sure my regex is incomplete, but I can't find the right one.
For example '/^h\w\we$/' didn't work.

any help? 
thank you

Comment: Replace `*` with `.` -- this matches any one non-newline character. (Assumes your word list has no spaces...)

Comment: thank you for you answer, but my problem is with word that contains the matching string. I think \w or . is indifferente, isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, you're right -- my brain was thinking `\w+` not just `\w`.